# How to store Boolean value in Mongodb using express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to store a Boolean in Mongodb but it always returns false.

Here's my database

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
```

This How I post the request using Postman

```
{ 
    "name": "aj",
    "password":"aj",
    "isAdmin": true
}
```

This is the result I get in my database

```
isAdmin:false
name:"aj"
password:"$2a$10$wBfElJ3YbZoOk3Bz/tyFc.uzZGuzStDppDCINZ8mZexZKumnDMmoW"
```

my post request route

```
router.post("/auth/signup", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(res);
  if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
    res.json({
      success: false,
      message: "Please enter your email and password"
    });
  } else {
    try {
      let newUser = new User();
      newUser.name = req.body.name;
      newUser.email = req.body.email;
      newUser.password = req.body.password;

      await newUser.save();
      let token = jwt.sign(newUser.toJSON(), process.env.SECRET, {
        expiresIn: 604800 //1 WEEK
      });

      res.json({
        success: true,
        token: token,
        message: "Successfully created"
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        message: err.message
      });
    }
  }
});
```

How can I set it to true or false when registering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```js
let newUser = new User();
newUser.name = req.body.name;
newUser.email = req.body.email;
newUser.password = req.body.password;

await newUser.save();
```

Do this:

```js
const newUser = await User.create({
  name = req.body.name,
  password = req.body.password,
  isAdmin = req.body.isAdmin
})
```

---

Note that you were trying to create a new user with `email` property, which you didn't even send in the request and which does not exist in the Model.

Also note that creating a new user with `isAdmin` property sent in the request is not secure, since everyone would be able to create new accounts with the admin role.

Comment: thank you this worked.... if i may ask how can i give admin access to speific routes

Comment: For admins, usually, it's best to give admin role manually. So you would create a user normally, and then update him to be an admin manually in the database.